# Search endpoint started returning groups

Tags: foursquare

About 30 mins ago the search endpoint started returning groups with a warning meta about deprecation of groups (not sure if the warning was there before).
No version change on my side:
end point https://api.foursquare.com/v2 and v=20140201 also tried with v=20140826.

```
    {
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "deprecated",
    "errorDetail": "This endpoint will stop returning groups in the future. Please use a current version, see http://bit.ly/vywCav."
  },
  "response": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "type": "nearby",
        "name": "Nearby",
        "items": [
          {
```

What is happening?

Comment: Yup ... same thing happened for me ... makes no sense ... I thought this was the reason the v parameter was added ... so nothing like this would happen

Comment: Previously I got the venues like this :
object.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("venues")
now there are no response-> venues ... only response -> groups -> items

Comment: Right Marc. The format now is the same as for explore endpoint (groups). Foursquare folks need to comment.

Comment: Sounds like a bug... they shouldn't be changing the API's behaviour without communicating its users in the developers page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foursquare is aware of the issue and is working on a fix.

https://twitter.com/foursquareapi/status/504381563040444417